# Youtube API fetch videos duration in getting playlist

Tags: video, youtube

I am trying to fetch videos details from `playlistId`. Though I am able to retrive details as well list of all videos but I am missing video duration, even as described in API Docs I am also missing starting time and end time as well.

My Requesting URL is like.

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key={MYAPIKEY}&part=id%2CcontentDetails%2Csnippet&playlistId=UUZSp2txrkbx8U8T2jM8qBNA&maxResults=50`

Response is -

```
[ { kind: 'youtube#playlistItem',
etag: '"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/qP8_ts1MTC2182AbfAh627bqqr4"',
id: 'UUREkNLQPHs-SSZYauOziXi0gAPODGW1Xc',
snippet: 
 { publishedAt: '2012-01-11T08:20:29.000Z',
   channelId: 'UCZSp2txrkbx8U8T2jM8qBNA',
   title: 'VIDEO TITLE HERE',
   description: '',
   thumbnails: [Object],
   channelTitle: 'XXX',
   playlistId: 'UUZSp2txrkbx8U8T2jM8qBNA',
   position: 0,
   resourceId: [Object] },
contentDetails: { videoId: 'jDcKLVcbRLI' // It is mentioned that I would receive video start and end time in detail. So I could calculate its playtime. } } ]
```

Where I am missing params or I am going wrong?

Comment: Hello Sankalp, Did you find any solution in this ? i am in same scenario

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution yet.